# How to connect to an ODBC connection stored on another computer

Tags: mysql, .net, odbc

I am developing a .Net application that requires a ODBC connection to an external vendor's MySQL database. The issue is that while doing development I cannot access this ODBC connection from my development machine. I have access to a remote server that can connect to the database. Is there a way to create a connection string on machine A (my dev machine) that can use the ODBC connection from machine B? I really want to avoid having to use this remote server for my actual development.

Comment: when you say you can not access this ODBC connection, you need to specify the reason why you can not access it. Also what kind of access do you have to the so called "remote server" of yours?

Comment: @levangode Good question. This is because of the way my company VPN works. The 3rd party whose database I connect to has whitelisted IP addresses from my company. However when I am on my company's VPN, my outbound internet traffic comes from my home IP (I WFH). I can setup the ODBC connection on a remote server which has outbound IP from my company's whitelisted IP.

Comment: refer to my answer below. Essentially, you will be always sending the traffic to the database server from your whitelisted IP. This is a common practice for similar scenarios. You should be able to look up particular tips for the installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you have 3 machines A,B,C

A has no access to C which it needs

B has access to C

A has access to B

you can set up a reverse-proxy server on B which will act as a mediator between A and C.

Now, in your scenario you can set up the reverse-proxy on your so called "remote server" and redirect the MYSQL traffic. Then set up the ODBC connection on your local machine to the "remote server" as if you were connecting to the MYSQL directly.

Depending on the possible limitations of your environments you are dealing with, this may or may not go smoothly, but that is the general idea.